# Editing content of custom tags in VisualEditor (MediaWiki)?

Tags: mediawiki, custom-tags, custom-tag, visual-editor

is it possible to make custom MediaWiki tags (as described [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Tag_extensions)) edit-able in VisualEditor?

When it is (which I guess) - are there *any* resources on this topic? I know there is no real documentation for VisualEditor, but I guess a lot of people had to do this, so maybe someone wrote down what he did?

I guess I have to extend the VisualEditor Data Model and add translations between it and HTML for what my specific tags do, but I can't real find where/how to do so.

Comment: You could try looking at some existing example, such as [Math](https://git.wikimedia.org/tree/mediawiki%2Fextensions%2FMath/master/modules%2Fve-math).